# How to use existing/Predefined table in android?

Tags: android, sql, database

Hi everyone i have one question i.e. i have some database table's which are already exist in database but i am not able to use them in my application. I am able to connect to database but i am not getting the tables which i have already created. I am not creating tables programmectically but i want to use existing table in my database. If i am creating tables programmetically then it's fine but how can i use existing table.
If anyone is having any idea plz suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question is simpelly copy your database by using the followig code.

private void CopyDataBase() throws IOException {

```
    // open the local database 
        InputStream copy = context.getAssets().open(UR_DB_NAME);

    // path where database is created 
    String path_DB = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty dbOut as the output stream
    OutputStream dbOut = new FileOutputStream(path_DB);

    // copy database from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = copy.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        dbOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    dbOut.flush();
    dbOut.close();
    copy.close();
}
```